# Initialize a few arrays of data in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

I want to set up definitions of all the tetris:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct Tetris{
    std::vector<int> data;
    int getAt(int x, int y){return data.at(y*4+x);};
} tetris[6];

int main(){
    //stick
    tetris[0].data.resize(32);
    int array0[32]={0,0,0,0,
                    0,0,0,0,
                    1,1,1,1,
                    0,0,0,0,
                    0,1,0,0,
                    0,1,0,0,
                    0,1,0,0,
                    0,1,0,0};
    tetris[0].data.assign(array0,array0+32);

    //brick
    tetris[1].data.resize(16);
    int array1[16]={0,0,0,0,
                    0,1,1,0,
                    0,1,1,0,
                    0,0,0,0};
    tetris[1].data.assign(array1,array1+16);

    ...

}
```

In this way I'll need to define 6 arrays just for storing initialization data(`array0`, `array1`...), which is useless after the initialization. This seems quite inefficient and a waste of memory. I'm wondering if there's a way to delete those data after each usage?

**Update:**

If I want to reuse `array0`, say

```
    tetris[0].data.resize(32);
    int array0[32]={...};
    tetris[0].data.assign(array0,array0+32);

    //brick
    tetris[1].data.resize(16);
    delete array0;
    int array0[16]={...};
    tetris[1].data.assign(array0,array0+16);

    ...
```

The compiler will report error of "array0 redefinition". Is `delete` not working in this case?

Comment: Put them in their own function, so the stack space is reclaimed upon return.

Comment: 6 arrays * 16 ints * 4 bytes per int = 384 bytes.  Is that really something to be so worried about?

Comment: You need those object definitions, so create classes.
This will surely help You, perhaps even static.

You perhaps do not need the data anymore, but the values of Your objects in order to "play" tetris.

Create classes and then objects, IF YOU NEED them.
This will help You in a ) saving memory and b) arrays are not the right approach in this situation,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like to control the lifetime of statically allocated types, you can add in arbitrary scope resolution operators to do so.

```
int main()
{
    {
        //stick
        tetris[0].data.resize(16);
        int array0[16]={0,0,0,0,
                    0,0,0,0,
                    1,1,1,1,
                    0,0,0,0};
        tetris[0].data.assign(array0,array0+16);

        //brick
        tetris[1].data.resize(16);
        int array1[16]={0,0,0,0,
                    0,1,1,0,
                    0,1,1,0,
                    0,0,0,0};
        tetris[1].data.assign(array1,array1+16);
    }//THISONE
    //Do the rest of the work of main, without the pesky arrays sticking around.

}
```

In this example main, your tetris variable is still alive, because it is global.  But those arrays you declared will not stick around past "THISONE".

Note that I don't necessarily recommend this approach.  Creating a class, or using some other more standard approach is preferable.  But occasionally this is a nice little trick, to avoid using dynamic allocations that aren't necessary.

EDIT: This approach is probably better, though be sure you understand everything that is going on, otherwise you might be better off sticking with what you know.  Particularly if you don't understand all of the bad things I did in here, in order to get you an example quickly.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class stick;//Forward declaration so shape can make stick a "friend"

class shape {//This classe declaration should go in a .h file.
    static const int WIDTH = 4;
    static const int HEIGHT = 4;
    int array[WIDTH][HEIGHT];

public:


    shape(){
        for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
                array[i][j] = 0;
            }
            array[i][i] = 1;
        }
    }

    void printShape() {
        for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
                cout << array[i][j] << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

    friend class stick;
};

class stick: public shape {//This declaration should also go in a header file
public:
    stick() {
        for(int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
                if(i == 0) array[i][j] = 1;
                else array[i][j] = 0;
            }
        }
    }
};



int main(){

    shape planeShape;
    stick stickShape;
    cout << "PLAIN SHAPE: " << endl;
    planeShape.printShape();

    cout << endl << "STICK SHAPE: " << endl;
    stickShape.printShape();



    cout << endl << "PLANE SHAPE POINTER:" << endl;
    shape* shapePointer = &planeShape;
    shapePointer->printShape();

    cout << endl << "STICK SHAPE POINTER:" << endl;
    shapePointer = &stickShape;
    shapePointer->printShape();

}
```

Comment: Thanks @ChrisCM! How do you mean by creating a class for this case?

Comment: @Xun Yang: give me five minutes

Comment: Great thanks! Using inheritance and Initializing them in constructors seem like a good approach :)

Answer (score 2):

The instructions that constitute a program live in memory. So the fact that you're setting the values of `array0` explicitly with `array0[n]={0,0,1,...}` means that the values are already stored in memory via the code that assigns them and cannot be deleted.

Even if you switched to using pointers and dynamically allocated arrays, you would still have the contents of the array ever-present in memory due to the fact that they are hard-coded in the code that populates the arrays.

I would just go with your original setup, except don't re-use `array0`.  Have a different array for each case where you were going to use `array0`.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to generate the tiles programmatically, but there will be duplicate to take care of because of the symmetry, and some generated patterns might be bogus, for instance:

```
int array0[16]={0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,
                0,0,0,0,
                1,1,1,1};

int array0[16]={0,0,0,1,
                0,1,0,0,
                1,1,0,1,
                0,0,1,0};
```

could be produced by a generating algorithm which tries every combinations. 
To avoid the duplicates, you need to establish the rule of symmetry which exist in the tiles configurations. This would be a very interesting problem in the more general setting of [polyominoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino).

For tetris tiles, given that there are only a few valid configurations, that solution might be a bit too far fetched. You can however save up a little bit of memory space, by storing all the tiles in the same array, using each bits of the array elements to carry the information for each tile, and then use a bitmask to select the correct pattern.

Here's a little programme in C++11 doing the combination for you:

```
#include <array>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

#define WIDTH 4

typedef std::pair<int,int> coord_t;

coord_t coord(int x, int y) {
  return std::make_pair(x,y);
}

int index(const coord_t &c) {
  //std::cout << "getting (" << c.first << "," << c.second << ")" << std::endl;
  return c.first * WIDTH + c.second;
}

coord_t cw (const coord_t &c){ 
  int x = c.first;
  int y = c.second;
  return coord(WIDTH - 1 - y, x);
}

coord_t r0(const coord_t &c){
  return c;
}

coord_t r90(const coord_t &c){
  return r0(cw(c));
}

coord_t r180(const coord_t &c){
  return r90(cw(c));
}

coord_t r270(const coord_t &c){
  return r180(cw(c));
}

typedef coord_t (*rotate)(const coord_t &);


class tetro;

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &out, const tetro &t);

class tetro {

public:

  tetro(){ v.reserve(WIDTH * WIDTH); }

  tetro(const std::initializer_list<int> &data): v(data){
    std::cout << *this << std::endl;
  }

  tetro(const tetro &src) {
    for (int i = 0; i < WIDTH * WIDTH; i++)
      v[i] = src.v[i];
  }

  void set(coord_t c, int val){
    v[index(c)] = val;
  }

  int get(coord_t c) const {
    return v[index(c)];
  }

  void combine (int r, const tetro &b, rotate rot){
    int i,j;
    for (i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
      for (j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
        coord_t c = coord(i,j);
        set(c, get(c) | ( b.get(rot(c)) << r));
      }
    }
  }

private:

  std::vector<int> v;

};

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &out, const tetro &t){
  int i,j;
  for (i = 0; i < WIDTH; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < WIDTH; j++) {
      coord_t c = coord(i,j);
      out << t.get(c) << ",";
    }
    out << std::endl;
  }
  return out;
}

std::array<tetro, 6> vl {{

  {
    0,0,1,0,
    0,0,1,0,
    0,1,1,0,
    0,0,0,0
  },

  {
    0,0,0,0,
    0,1,1,0,
    0,1,1,0,
    0,0,0,0
  },

  {
    0,0,0,0,
    1,1,1,1,
    0,0,0,0,
    0,0,0,0
  },


  {
    0,1,0,0,
    0,1,0,0,
    0,1,1,0,
    0,0,0,0
  },

  {
    0,1,0,0,
    0,1,1,0,
    0,0,1,0,
    0,0,0,0
  },

  {
    0,0,0,0,
    1,1,1,0,
    0,1,0,0,
    0,0,0,0
  }

  }};

void combine(int rank, tetro &t, rotate rot){
  for (auto it = vl.begin(); it != vl.end(); ++it) {
    t.combine(rank, *it, rot);
    rank++;
  }
}

int main(){

  tetro t;
  int d = 6;
  combine(0, t, r0);
  combine(d, t, r90);
  combine(d+d, t, r180);
  combine(d+d+d, t, r270);

  std::cout << "result " << std::endl << t << std::endl;

}
```

It starts from the canonical and mirrored [tetrominoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetromino)  and build a single array of `int` containing all the variations, including all rotations of each tetromino. You could simply limit the code to the first combination - ie. without the rotations if you already have that handled by your code, and use an array of `char` instead, for a total of only 16 bytes of space consumed (not counting the space used by any additional code necessary to manipulate the data, which is left as an exercise...).

Otherwise, keep the whole data, and use the [flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) to implement your objects, each containing only the rank of the tetromino, as well as its rotation (`0`, `90`, `180`, and `270`, so 4 different states). You would have to include the whole array generated by the programme above (384 bytes), and write functions to compute the bitmask from the rank and the state (this can be deduced from the code of the provided programme).

Comment: Wow, this is mind blowing! The idea of mathematically generating blocks kept me wondering for hours. Great amount of things to learn from the example as well :) Currently I'm just storing all the rotations in the array as well to reduce problems of "kicking back".

Comment: Yeah, there's probably a math. domain devoted to that problem. Regarding the code, I realized that I missed one of the mirrors (there are 2 tiles which can be mirrored effectively: "L" shape and "S" shape - the second one is missing), but it should not be too difficult to correct that issue. I wonder how the original game did store that data.